# php- mssql server database connectivity using wamp server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have WAMP server installed in my system.
I have also installed MS SQL Server 2008 on the same system.

I want to make the connectivity of my php application with MS SQL Server.
I have tries with below code segment in my config.php file for database conenctivity.

---

```
<?php

 $conn=mssql_connect('localhost','DINKDEV2\Administrator','dink@123') or die('not connect');
 mssql_select_db('nevis_pharma_company');
 if( $conn ) {
   echo "Connection established.<br />";
 }else{
   echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
?>
```

Comment: did you even check the doc? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `mssql_connect` is

```
mssql_connect('servername','username','password',bool);
```

so you have to specify the msSql servername instead of localhost.

You can also try PDO

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=hostname,port;Database=dbName", "Username", "Password");
```

Comment: yes, but it will work in `SQL` server? since php has uses `mssql_connect ` for that matters, so im guessing you had try this?

Comment: Hi,I have tried but still it gives same error message that mssql_connect() is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `localhost`

```
$conn=mssql_connect('.\SQLEXPRESS','DINKDEV2\Administrator','dink@123') or die('not connect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$conn = mssql_connect(  "servername", "DINKDEV2\Administrator", "dink@123" )
         or die( "not connect")
```

Comment: When i am running the application it gives me below error message.
----------------------------------------------

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\wamp\www\nevis_pharma\company\config.php on line 7
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 145496 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.0020 147928 include( 'C:\wamp\www\nevis_pharma\company\config.php' ) ..\index.php:2

------------------------------------------------
look into the matter and resolve as soon as possible.